# Renaming terms of the eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: matrix, replacement, symbolic, eigenvalues

I have a matrix (DpT2) with complicated eigenvalues that I'm hoping to simplify.

```
c11[a_, e_, v_] := (1 - e) L/(R0*v^2) - 1
c12[a_, e_, v_] := a (1 - e^2) L/v^2
c21[a_, e_, v_] := 1/(a (1 + e)) ((1 - e) L/(v^2 R0*R1) - 1/R0 - 1/R1)
c22[a_, e_, v_] := (1 - e) L/(R1*v^2) - 1

d11[a_, e_, v_] := (1 + e) L/(R1*v^2) - 1
d12[a_, e_, v_] := a (1 - e^2) L/v^2
d21[a_, e_, v_] := 1/(a (1 - e)) ((1 + e) L/(v^2 R0*R1) - 1/R0 - 1/R1)
d22[a_, e_, v_] := (1 + e) L/(R0*v^2) - 1

Dp0T = {{c11[a, e, v], c12[a, e, v]}, {c21[a, e, v], c22[a, e, v]}};
Dp1T = {{d11[a, e, v], d12[a, e, v]}, {d21[a, e, v], d22[a, e, v]}};

DpT2 = Dp1T . Dp0T ;
Simplify[DpT2 ] // MatrixForm
Simplify[Det[DpT2]]
Eigenvalues[DpT2]
```

I want Mathematica to somehow use the replacement

```
{DpT2[[1, 1]] -> a10, DpT2[[1, 2]] -> a01, DpT2[[2, 1]] -> b10, 
 DpT2[[2, 2]] -> b01}
```

so that the eigenvalues are given with respect to the $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ instead.

I appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you replace:

```
{DpT2[[1, 1]] -> a10, DpT2[[1, 2]] -> a01, DpT2[[2, 1]] -> b10, 
 DpT2[[2, 2]] -> b01}
```

you simply get a matrix:

```
m = {{a10, a01}, {b10, b01}}
```

and determinant and Eigenvalues:

```
Det[m]
Eigenvalues[m]
```

[image]